# I deploy project on GITHUB pages not appear on browser

Tags: github-pages

I deploy an angular project on GitHub successfully but when I click on the link of the project  documentation appear instead of project How can I open the project on browser. the link of the project is https://khaledelmasry247.github.io/myNote/
[image: this is the image of project on browser]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced the similar issue long back with my repository. You can check these steps:

1. navigate to repository
2. Go to settings of your repository
3. In the options section, navgate to github pages.
4. In the source select "root" as shown below.
5. Then check it once.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/) that runs by default on GitHub Pages.
You can disable it by adding the file `.nojekyll` in the root of your project.

More here:
https://github.blog/2009-12-29-bypassing-jekyll-on-github-pages/

Answer (score 0):

In order for GitHub pages to work with your project, you will need to build the angular project and push the built artifacts to your repository. You will also need to tell GitHub which directory to look at for your built files. It will look for index.html by default. Looking at your repo, it looks like you have already built your project and the files are in your `gh-pages` branch. You will need to do something like @[KushalSeth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4393351/kushalseth) suggests, except in your instance, you will have to change it to look at the `gh-pages` [branch](https://github.com/khaledelmasry247/myNote/tree/gh-pages).

1. Click on the `Settings` for your project.
2. Scroll down to the `GitHub Pages` section.
3. Change the branch to your `gh-pages` branch.
4. Save.